# Distinguishing between "opposites" of "ortho-"

Tags: word-choice, etymology

There is a class of transformations in physics called "orthochronous", meaning that they preserve the direction of time's flow.  ("Ortho-" from the Greek for 'straight' or 'right'?)  As far as I am aware, while there is no *word* for the opposite---a transformation that *reverses* time's flow---there is certainly such a *concept*.  So I need the word to describe that concept, and I can easily think of two possibilities.  But I am unclear about the distinctions between them.

- Heterochronous.  ("Hetero-" from the Greek for 'other'?)
- Parachronous.  ("Para-" from the Greek for 'amiss', 'irregular', or 'distinct from'?)

I would lean toward hetero-, but I'm not entirely sure why.  My attempts at establishing the Greek origins are amateurish and tentative, of course.

Is there a strong distinction between these two options?  If so, which best describes my desired usage; if not, should I just pick one at random?

(I'm also entirely open to better options.)

Comment: If you are willing to mix Latin and Greek, perhaps *retrochronous*?

Comment: How about  *merlinchronous*?? ;-)

Comment: Well, if "ortho" means "right" there's always "sinister".  (But seriously, when speaking about time I'd think "retro" would work.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Greek prefix "*ortho*-" means "right" (in the sense of "*correct*", ultimately deriving from "straight"), so strictly speaking the antonym should have a Greek prefix meaning "wrong", but neither "*dyschronous*" nor "*cacochronus*" quite works.

So perhaps instead of the antonym of "wrong", we could use the antonym of "straight", i.e. "bent" or "crooked", for which the closest Greek prefix is "*scoli*-", rendering "***scolichronous***".¹

But I don't particularly like that, either: something moving against the flow of time isn't following a *crooked* path, nor even a *wrong* path, it's simply *backwards*, as in swimming upriver (which is neither wrong nor crooked).

So perhaps we'd like a prefix which means "*against*" or "*backwards*".  The Greek prefix "*ana*-" means "against", so one option is "***anachronous***" (and the related English word "[anachronism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anachronism)" does indeed mean "*chronologically misplaced*", especially something from the past that doesn't belong here in the present; it is *against time*).

Another option, which I prefer, is "***retrochronous***"; the drawback is "retro" is a Latin root, but that's outweighed, in my opinion, by the benefits: "*retro*-" is both more consonant with "*ortho*-" (ending with *o*) and more immediately accessible (few know what "*ana*-" means, but everyone knows what "*retro*-" means).

---

¹ I also considered "*scalen*-" (meaning "uneven", as in "scalene triangle"), for "*scalenochronous*", but that's a mouthful and no real improvement over "*scolichronous*", and "*presbychronous*" for "old time", but that lacks a sense of motion.

Comment: _Ana-_ doesn't really mean ‘wrong’ as such (that's more like _dys-_, though that's really closer to ‘bad’); it just means ‘against’ or ‘back’. In that sense, _anachronous_ is a good antonym to _orthochronous_. It's easily confused with anachronisms, though, which are a different thing.

Comment: I like the feel of "ana-", certainly, but I do share Janus's reservation about confusion with anachronism.  Any thoughts about "hetero-" or "para-"?

Comment: "*Hetero*-" means "mixed", so that would work if you had a mixed bag of tachyons, luxons and bradyons, but that's not the situation here. Similarly, "*para*-" means "beside", so that would work for something outside of time, or progressing along a separate or parallel timeline, as in a multiple worlds ("*Sliders*") scenario.

Comment: Oops, it looks like "*hetero*" means "*different (from usual)*", not "*mixed*". That's improves its suitability, relatively speaking, but to me still doesn't seem specific enough: *heterochronous* might mean "accelerated time", or "decelerated time", or "out of chronological order", or "choppy time", or anything else that's not "plain old time". With that said, it is preferable to other options, for ending in an "`o`", as "ortho" does.

Comment: I quite like dyschronous. I think it's a reasonable fit.

Answer (score 3):

anti-chronus sounds better to me, b.c anti- has the sense of against

Answer (score 1):

You could try **cacochronous**, where the greek root *caca-* or *caco-* [means](http://wordinfo.info/unit/2422/ip:1/il:C)

> bad, harsh, wrong, evil; incorrect; unpleasant; poor; used most of the time as a prefix

There are several example words at the link that use this prefix.

Comment: Funny, I added to this answer at the same time you did.

Comment: @DanBron - yeah, I hate when that happens.

Comment: I would suggest using the _k_ though to indicate the Greek origin. The _c_ is decidedly non-Greek.

Comment: My concern is that there should be no value judgement -- neither direction can be specified as good/bad, right/wrong.  (Maybe orthochronous is imperfectly formed, but we're stuck with it...)

Comment: @oerkelens It's _calligraphy_ and _cacophony_, though, so using a k would actually probably be more confusing than anything.

Comment: Also, by that logic, it looks like khronous would be on the menu...  :)