# A toned down term to replace "orthodoxy" in sociology of art

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, neologisms, derivational-morphology, greek

I think this community could help me a lot. In sociology of culture the term **orthodoxy** refers to ideas held by most and imposed by cultural institutions, so that the "doxa", or opinion, is maintained for a long time and is difficult to depart from. In art, this would easily apply to the academic art of the XVII to XIX centuries, but the closer you get to the second half of the last century and to our times, the more fluid these ideas get, because many cultural institutions compete and no institution can really impose ideas as strongly.

So I think a softened term would be needed instead of orthodoxy, so that one would be able to refer to ideas that are shared by many for some time. Ideally a neologism, replacing the prefix "ortho-" and keeping "-doxy", both to refer to "opinion" and to keep some familiarity with the term replaced. Could you help?

Comment: Hello, Fla Brites, Welcome to ELU! Just to be clear, _coining_ of neologisms is off-topic here, as per [this post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/how-should-we-handle-single-word-requests-that-dont-have-a-matching-word) and the other [documentation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (questions here should have real answers about _actual usage_). If you are asking for a single word (which may or not be available!), can you please give a sample sentence with a blank where you would use it? Cheers!

Comment: If you really want to keep the _-doxy_, beware of these, harvested from the [English Speculum](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/speculum.txt): _adoxy
paradoxy
amidoxy
cacodoxy
pseudodoxy
hyperothodoxy
orthodoxy
ultraorthodoxy
unorthodoxy
iodoxy
heterodoxy_.

Comment: Hello, Conrado. Indeed, there is much more about language as it is here than about language as it could be. But coining, creating and modifying is also part of the historical development of languages. As a social scientist I'd better ask for the help of experts. I read a brilliant discussion here, coincidentally on the substitution of "ortho-" for the coining a new scientific term. Although I found the answers given there amazing, the meaning I intend for the substitution is different. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192600/distinguishing-between-opposites-of-ortho

Comment: *zeitgeist*.  Sorry, it's not greek.

Comment: That said, you seem to want something that reflects not *demo* doxy, but *aristo* doxy or maybe *paideia* doxy.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, Stevesliva. Zeitgeist is also a term connected to a very platonic idea of Spririt, or Idea, of a pre-sociological way of thinking about society and ideas. It entails a way of thinking that sees Thought as if it were something that stands all around us, like air, the "atmosphere" as people say. Current sociological thought sees thinking as a kind of symbolic weapon of groups in struggle for symbolic dominance. But, as there is today no institution that can impose the "right" way, an orthodoxy, we might talk about "doxa" (opinion) that is dominant, instead of "right".

Comment: As it's the opinion of specialized cultural groups fighting for dominance, I don't think *demo* would be a good prefix. Also with *aristo*.. I thought of it, but as it implies "best"... I have to say, I'm currently debating (with myself, but I thought I could be debating with this learned community) if **pleistodoxa** wouldn't be a good option. though I thought of *atleo*, and *entea* and *agon* as good candidates for a prefix to *doxa*, to convey the meaning of "ideas as instruments in a battle for symbolic dominance".

Comment: pleistodoxa was already coined by Coleridge

Answer (score 1):

No single word seems to turn up, but the standard term for what is generally believed about a particular subject by both experts and the general public is **the conventional wisdom.** The phrase is part of the title of a book: *Untruth: Why the Conventional Wisdom Is (Almost Always) Wrong,* by Robert Samuelson, an economist of the mid-nineteenth century.

https://books.google.com/books?id=-iYbbnT0cQIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22conventional+wisdom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPx-vcyrPtAhWlFjQIHYAjAZ8Q6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22conventional%20wisdom%22&f=false

Comment: Hi, Xane. Thank you for sharing. Unfortunately, "conventional wisdom" doesn't cut a good answer in the sociological debate. I am glad you brought this classic up, but the academic debate has advanced, and the term is considered, today, too imprecise. The 19th century term was used in a time when "Thought" was considered from a platonic sense. *Doxa, orthodoxy* and *heterodoxy* are terms of a current debate in which sociologists relate not thought (which is vague), but discourse (what is actually said or written), to social hierarchical positions within disputing groups of cultural production.